# Adding to an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, append

I am trying to add a string named `temp` to the end of an array named `fourth_degree` with the following Swift code:

```
 fourth_degree.append(temp)
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: "fourth_degree" is a 'let' constant.
```

Comment: Please add context.  Show how `fourth_degree` is created.

Comment: Please **read** the error message. It's pretty much self-explanatory. And this is not PHP or javascript: Variable names are supposed to be *camelCased*.

Comment: use `var fourth_degree: [String] = []` to declare your variable. Use `var` instead of `let`. `var` is for variable while `let` is for constant. Array in swift is a value type, `append` mutates the value.

Comment: This is a low quality question. You both don't provide enough information to answer it, and make no attempt to understand the error message you are getting.

Comment: And it's another *dump-and-run* question.  Posters really need to hang around for a while and add clarifying information.

Answer (score 0):

Just change let to var in the declaration of your array;

```
var yourArray: [YourArrayType] = []
```